# Could not find pg-0.12.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am not able to make new rails project because everytime i am running any rails command like "rails new" or simply "rails" i get an error "Could not find pg-0.12.2 in any of the sources".

Comment: try in your console and `project root`:  `gem install pg`.

Comment: Been there done that but Problem still persists

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: fixed. In my parent folder i was having a rails application whose gemfile's pg gem was missing and that was causing the error.... Just removed that unwanted application from parent folder and now it seems working...!!